# Razor sharp html link differ from the executed link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

While creating a custom pager I came across the problem when I send an string to my view and I encode it as @raw(strHTML) it will automatically add a controller name in front of all my links. On initial load the pager is loaded correctly and no extra controllername was added. When I hit the next button a get request is done to the action and the next page has to be loaded and this will also create a new pager. The outputted html is exactly the same as the first time this was executed. The html that is created by my customPager while debugging:

```
<ul>
    <li class='previousPage'><span>Previous</span></li>
    <li class='currentPage'><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a title='Next page' rel='next nofollow' href='Invoices/Index?page=2'>2 </a></li>
    <li><a title='Next page' rel='next nofollow' href='Invoices/Index?page=3'>3 </a></li>
    <li><a title='Next page' rel='next nofollow' href='Invoices/Index?page=4'>4 </a></li>
    <li><a title='Next page' rel='next nofollow' href='Invoices/Index?page=5'>5 </a></li>
    <li class='nextPage'><a title='Volgende pagina' rel='next nofollow' href='Invoices/Index?page=2'>Volgende</a></li>
</ul>
```

The html is correct, but when the page is rendered and I hover over the link it reproduces the following link:

```
localhost:xxxx/company/Invoices/Invoices/Index?page=1
```

company is the area, Invoices the controller , second Invoices (NOT necessary, this breaks the link), index the action name.

I was wondering how the html and the reproduced link while clicking in the browser can be different.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not hardcode the href property value, Use the [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper method instead. It will fix your problem.

**Replace**

```
href='Invoices/Index?page=2'
```

**with**

```
href='@Url.Action("Index","Invoices",new { page=2 })'
```

**EDIT:**(As per the comment) :

**If you want to use Url.Action method in your custom class**

Pass the `RequestContext` to your custom class from the controller. I would add a Constructor to your custom class to handle this.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class PaginationCustom
{
    private UrlHelper _urlHelper;
    public PaginationCustom(UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        _urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }
    public string GetPagingMarkup()
    {
        //add your relevant html markup here
        string html = "<div>";
        string url = _urlHelper.Action("Index", "Invoices", new { id = 3 });
        html= html+"<a href='"+url + "'>3</a></div>";
        return html;
    }
}
```

You need to import `System.Web.Mvc` namespace to this class to use the `UrlHelper` class.

Now in your controller, create an object of this class and pass the controller context,

```
UrlHelper uHelp = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
var paging = new PaginationCustom(uHelp );

//Now call the method to get the Paging markup.
string pagingMarkup = paging.GetPagingMarkup();
```

Comment: The answer u gave is to use inside the razorsharp view. Maybe I haven't made my question 100% clear. The html that will be displayed is created inside the class PaginationCustom.cs. Inside this class I cannot use the Url.Action right? If I can can u tell me what to import or what the syntax is? I resolved on Url and this imports :
using System.Security.Policy; --> which isn't the one i need. Thanks for your time

Comment: Thx for the nice update! I think I'm very close now, but there is still one thing to do, the <a>-tag is not added to the html... it just generetes the output : <li>/company/Invoices/Index/2</li> , what is the remaining problem?

Comment: @thomvlau `Url.Action` method returns only the href value(ex :Invoice/index/2). You still need to add the <a href things in the code. I missed it.

Comment: @thomvlau I updated the answer with what you are looking for.